# Can't use pyarrow dictionary in scheme when appending tables to file

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I have a very large dataset which i am attempting to process in chunks. The source data is a pandas dataframe, which I am able to read in pieces and process chunk-by-chunk. I am attempting to then write the chunks to a pyarrow feather file, appending chunks as they are processed. When writing these chunks I am using the following approach:

```
  import pyarrow as pa
  fp = pa.OSFile('my_file.arrow', 'wb')
  schema = pa.schema(
      [
          ('localtime', pa.timestamp('ns')),
          ('exchtime', pa.timestamp('ns')),
          ('msgtype', pa.string()),
          ('symbol', pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.string())),
          ('exch', pa.string()),
          ('price', pa.float64()),
          ('size', pa.float64()),
          ('side', pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.string())),
          ('ref', pa.uint64()),
          ('oldref', pa.uint64()),
          ('mpid', pa.string()),
          ('esd', pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.string())),
          ('platform', pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.string())),
      ]
  )
  writer = pa.ipc.new_file(fp, schema)

  ...

  for df in [... list of dataframes chunks ...]:
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)
    writer.write(table)

  writer.close()
  fp.close()
```

This all works fine if I don't use the pa.dictionary() data type in the schema. Unfortunately, this also results in very large files, since pyarrow isn't able to index string fields with common repeating values (e.g. "symbol" in the example above has the same string in every entry; "exch" is one of ~20 values, etc).

Running the code as written above generates an error string: "Dictionary replacement detected when writing IPC file format. Arrow IPC files only support a single non-delta dictionary for a given field across all batches."

I think the issue is that, even when you use an explicit schema for converting the dataframe to a table, the dictionary mapping of strings to values might be different depending on which particular strings appear.

Is there a way to explicitly provide this dictionary mapping (of string to integer) if the possible string values can be known ahead of time?

Some things that I've tried:

- Works if you don't use dictionary types
- Dictionary types work if every chunk has the same value in a column, e.g. symbol
- Doesn't work if you infer the schema for each chunk, rather than explicitly setting it, because schema inference is not constant across chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emit_dictionary_deltas` in [IpcWriteOptions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.ipc.IpcWriteOptions.html#pyarrow.ipc.IpcWriteOptions) must be set to `True` in order for this to work.

```py
import pyarrow as pa

fp = pa.OSFile("my_file.arrow", "wb")
schema = pa.schema(
    [
        ("symbol", pa.dictionary(pa.int8(), pa.string())),
    ]
)

options = pa.ipc.IpcWriteOptions(emit_dictionary_deltas=True)
writer = pa.ipc.new_file(fp, schema, options=options)
writer.write(pa.table({"symbol": ["A", "B"]}, schema=schema))
writer.write(pa.table({"symbol": ["A", "B", "C"]}, schema=schema))
```

I think the reason it is not enabled by default is it causes compatibility issues with other implementations that don't support it